# Run Java Script from C# Code Behind no Button

Tags: javascript, c#

I have an asp web application and need to call a JavaScript confirm function from within a C# if statement.  I am a very very weak on JavaScript so be gentle.  Here is my JavaScript I have placed on the ASPX page:

```
function Confirm() 
{
    var result = window.confirm('Are you sure?');
    if (result == true)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

here is the C# code when I want to call this script.  What I am trying to accomplish is check 2 values on my aspx page the first is a CaseID and the second in the value of a checkbox.  If the code runs I want to show the confirmation box and if they click yes then redirect to another page.

```
else if (rec.Count != 0 && rec.Select(s=> s.IsClosed).First().Value == true && chkOverRide.Checked == false)
{
     //if the case is closed and not overridded redirects to edit page
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
           this,
           GetType(),
           "key",
           "confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?');",
           true);
      Response.Redirect("~\\Forms\\EditRecord.aspx?CaseId="+ rec.Select(s => s.CaseNum).First(), false);
      return false;
}
```

I have tried this but nothing happens I do not get a confirmation box the code just falls thru and runs the redirect. Thanks

Comment: Your function in Javascript has a typo.  You typed Confim instead of Confirm.  Notice the missing "r".

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to have all the logic in javascript and only call code-behind after you have confirmation?

Comment: Thanks @Doug F I have kind of figured out why I am not seeing the message.  First I fixed the spelling error and then I removed the C# redirect code.  The message now pops but I need to figure out how to get the value of the java script message click and respond to that value.  Any suggestion on how I can get the value of the click?

Comment: Do you mean you want the message 'Are you sure you want to continue?' in your confirm text box instead of 'Are you sure?'?  If so, you have to make your Confirm Javascript function accept a parameter and use that variable in your call to window.confirm.  If you mean to do something else, however, please clarify.

Comment: What I am trying to do is run a java script that will have a parameter and show the user a message that says " This record already exists do you wish to reopen it for editing"  and give them an OK button or a Cancel button.  If they click OK I will redirect the user to another aspx page in my project.  For some reason I cannot get the java script to even run a simple alert function for testing.

Answer (score 0):

As I worked thru this problem I found I had some issues that were causing my failures.  The first issue was I was using a C# redirect which was causing a post back so my JavaScript code never showed the JavaScript box.  I had to rethink the process and ended up using JavaScript to do the redirect.  Here is what the new JavaScript looks like.

```
function Confirm(caseId) {
            var result = window.confirm('This case already exists and completed. Please reopen it for further updates?');
            if (result == true)
                window.location = '\EditRecord.aspx?CaseNum='+caseId;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

And the C# Method now looks like this:

```
else if (rec.Count != 0 && rec.Select(s=> s.IsClosed).First().Value == true && chkOverRide.Checked == false)
            {//if the case is closed and not overridded redirects to edit page
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,GetType(),"key", "Confirm('" + CaseNumber + "');", true);
```

Method now works as expected.